# How do I change my camera view?

Tags: halo-4

Is there a way to change the camera view while playing to show the man I am playing with?

Comment: I am assuming you are placing emphasis on the "while playing" part.  From the "theater" mode you can view yourself from a variety of angles - but only during a video playback - not while playing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to directly change the camera view so that you can view your character.

However, there are certain things you can do in game to make the camera view change. Your camera view will change to third-person view with your character visible if you do one of the following things:

- Get into any seat of a warthog
- Get into a ghost
- Get into either seat of a mongoose
- Pick up a mounted turret
- Perform an assassination
- Activate an armor ability

Answer (score 1):

you turned on the skull that remove your view of the weapon and HUD. Just go to the campaign main screen, go to skulls, and deactivate it (Blind)

Answer (score -1):

is a direction  hwo can help you

Comment: Please don't leave link or video only answers, since they may become unavailable in the future.  It'd be greatly appreciated if you summarized the contents of the video.